# Enumeration in Java

Tags: java, enumeration

I'd like to know what is wrong with my code

```
public static enum e_option
{
        HELP,
        AUTHOR,
        PROJ_NAME,
        DESC,
        MAIN_CLASS_NAME,
        BASE_DIR,
        XML_NAME,
        RULE_OPT,
        UNKNOWN
}
```

the i have this method which is

```
public e_option s2i(String arg)
    {
        e_option opt = null;
        if (arg.equals("--help"))
        {
            opt = HELP;
        }
        if (arg.equals("--author"))
        {
            opt = AUTHOR;
        }

    }
```

the problem is eclipse doesn't recognize HELP and AUTHOR. It suggest me to create new constants which is bizzare.

Comment: sorry for the format, usually stackoverflow recognize automatically the code

Comment: SO does *not* automatically recognize code. As it says in the help box when you're asking your question, "► indent code by 4 spaces". If your code is already indented at least 4 spaces on each line (and a blank line before the code), it will work. In your case, you have a few lines that are not already indented, so it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

To get an `enum`'s value you have to use its name:

```
opt = e_option.HELP;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try e_option.HELP instead of HELP?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the enum name:

```
opt = e_option.HELP;
```

Answer (score 0):

Among other things, it is wrong that you promise to return an e_option, but you don't do it.

Comment: i'll do it actually i don't show all the code to simplify the presentation

Comment: This is noble, but you should make sure your simplifying does not introduce new bugs. It is also a good idea to copy/paste the exact compiler message one gets for the simplified example. Far too often one see questions like: *Plz help, why is compiler error?!?!* followed by dozens of line of code. Yours was slightly better, but still can be imporved.